# Second classification class got zero on all metrics

Tags: keras, neural-network, classification

I have a dataset of [red wine quality dataset on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/red-wine-quality-cortez-et-al-2009) which I have to classify them binarily. I'm using neural network:

```
    model_nn = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(128, LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1), input_shape=(11,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
])
model_nn.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model_nn.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
#test_loss, test_acc = model_nn.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

I would say it performs fairly well with details:

```
Epoch 50/50
48/48 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2660 - accuracy: 0.8875 - val_loss: 0.3130 - val_accuracy: 0.8741
```

However, I wanted to see its performance using another metrics like precision, recall and f1 score. So, after searchng through the internet, I got this code and adjust with my case:

```
# make probability predictions with the model
pred_nn = model_nn.predict(X_test)
print(pred_nn)
print(y_test)

# Evaluate on test data
print('\n---- Test data ----')
accuracy = sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, np.argmax(pred_nn, axis=1))
print('Accuracy: {0:.2f}'.format(accuracy * 100.0))
print('Classification Report:')
print(sklearn.metrics.classification_report(y_test, np.argmax(pred_nn, axis=1)))
print('Confusion Matrix:')
print(sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, np.argmax(pred_nn, axis=1)))
```

The resulit was quite surprising, although it worked quite well for classifying class zero, it is unable to predict **any metrics** for class number two:

```
---- Test data ----
Accuracy: 86.43
Classification Report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.86      1.00      0.93       968
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00       152

    accuracy                           0.86      1120
   macro avg       0.43      0.50      0.46      1120
weighted avg       0.75      0.86      0.80      1120

Confusion Matrix:
[[968   0]
 [152   0]]
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1272: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
```

Where did I miss? I know there is something wrong with this but im not really sure whether it came from my model or the dataset itself,

Comment: what is the proportion of class1 and class2 in the training dataset?

Comment: Can you also elaborate the statement `"I have to classify them binarily"`? How are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the testing label (y test) and the results, if the predicted results are decimal number and the y_test is binary data, then do `np.round` for the predicted results to make them both binary.